# I'm new to PHP and trying to divide three numbers in order to get the SMA of the code

Tags: php, html

i am still new at php so i am just trying to figure out how i divide three values in order to get the sma

i have tried couple many times but it is not giving me the SMA it just giving me another number!! what can i do

```
$number1=$_POST['number1'];       
$number2=$_POST['number2'];          
$number3=$_POST['number3'];         
echo $number1+$number2+$number3 /3;
```

the actual result that im looking for instance: 20+5+5 is 30 and the SMA of it is 10 but my code is showing that is 16.666666667..!!! why is that

Comment: Shouldn't you add parentheses around the sum? (number1+number2+number3)/3

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ($number1+$number2+$number3) /3;
```

It's a problem of priority between the additions and the division.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this in case you have more values:

```
$values = array($_POST['number1'], $_POST['number2'], $_POST['number3']);
$values = array_filter($values); /* To remove potential null values */

echo array_sum($values) / count($values);
```

Comment: You have created and set really high benchmarks for your peers with you excellent quality work. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should read about what [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in PHP is:

> For example, in the expression 1 + 5 * 3, the answer is 16 and not 18 because the multiplication ("*") operator has a higher precedence than the addition ("+") operator. Parentheses may be used to force precedence, if necessary. For instance: (1 + 5) * 3 evaluates to 18.

Therefore your expression must be written as `($number1+$number2+$number3)/3`, not `$number1+$number2+$number3 /3;`

Comment: I highly respect your effort and wish to thank you for the commendable work which you delivered.

Comment: Thanks. Please upvote any answer you think helped you and accept one as correct answer, as suggested in Help Center [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).